# Not Locating My Blade File (Laravel + Voyager)

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys i'm trying to make a custom view `generate.blade.php` in laravel(voyager) with a custom resource controller `GeneratePdfController` but whenever i click the button that redirects me to the view it and tell me that 
 "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." .The location of all the files are located at the default directory except for the `pdf-page.blade.php`. Anyone able to point out what am i missing inside?.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/dashboard/attendance/generate', 'GeneratePdfController@index');
Route::resource('generateReport','GeneratePdfController');
```

**GeneratePdfController**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Attendance;

class GeneratePdfController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $att = Attendance::all();

        return view('generate')->with('attt',$att);
    }

}
```

**generate.blade.php**

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    <form method="post" action="{{url('generateReport')}}">
          <!-- To Do Functions -->
    </form>
@endsection
```

**pdf-page.blade.php**

This blade is located in the \app\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\partials

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="bulk_delete_btn"  href="{{url('/dashboard/attendance/generate')}}"><i class="voyager-trash"></i> <span>Generate Report</span></a>
```

**EDIT**

From the research i have done, i suspect that by default voyager will not search for the blade file and other controller in other sub folders aside from `TCG`sub folders. Then i tried making a blade file inside `Vendor/TCG/voyager/resource/views` and added a in function in the `VoyagerController` to return the view and edited the `voyager.php` with a `Route::get` but it did not work either. Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am beginner too but I might have done something similar:
I added a route 'admin/test/' to the file -> laravel-project/vendor/tcg/voyager/routes/voyager.php which looks like plain old laravel route:

[image]

The blade view is actually located in laravel-project/views/ directory. It has the following code:
[image]

Which gives me something like this if I visit the route '/admin/test':

[image]

Hope this helps.